# Python Translate Telephone Letter to Number Question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this has been asked before on this site, but I was unable to understand the answers given (I'm still very new), so I'm going to try and ask again. My assignment is to write code that takes a 10 digit phone number (XXX-XXX-XXXX) and converts any letters (i.e. 800-FLO-WERS) to numbers. I've wracked my brain on this, and could really use some help/explanations. In the class I'm taking (using the excellent "Starting out with Python, 4th edition, by Tony Gaddis), I cannot use concepts we have not covered (like dictionaries), but I can use lists/tuples. The code I've come up with follows:

```
def main():
    try:
        user_number = str(input('Enter a phone number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): ')).upper()
        converted_number = check_number(user_number)
        print('The phone number is:',converted_number
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
def check_number(user_number):
    try:
        for char in user_number:
            if char.isalpha():
                result = convert_to_num(char)
                return result
            else:
                return char
        return converted_number
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
def convert_to_num(char):
    if char in ['A','B','C']:
        char = 2
    elif char in ['D','E','F']:
        char = 3
    elif char in ['G','H','I']:
        char = 4
    elif char in ['J','K','L']:
        char = 5
    elif char in ['M','N','O']:
        char = 6
    elif char in ['P','Q','R','S']:
        char = 7
    elif char in ['T','U','V']:
        char = 8
    elif char in ['W','X','Y','Z']:
        char = 9
    return char
main()
```

Obviously, I'm not sure how to store the converted letter-to-number (considered doing it by indexing, but couldn't quite make that work either). I'm not looking for anyone to do my work for me, but a detailed explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be lovely.

Comment: your "for char in user_number:" loop never actually gets to run through its full duration, because your if/else conditions have a "return" keyword in it. the moment a return is encountered, the function stops and returns whatever it was instructed to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `return` is to return to the function where it was called. Here since `return` is inside the loop. It will exit the function in the first iteration.

```
for char in user_number:
     if char.isalpha():
           result = convert_to_num(char)
           return result
     else:
           return char
     return converted_number
```

Just use a list instead to store the converted values then return them after the loop using the `join()` method.

```
def main():
    try:
        user_number = str(input('Enter a phone number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): ')).upper()
        converted_number = check_number(user_number)
        print('The phone number is:',converted_number)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

def check_number(user_number):
    try:
        r = []
        for char in user_number:
            if char.isalpha():
                result = convert_to_num(char)
                r.append(str(result))
            else:
                r.append(char)
        return "".join(r)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

def convert_to_num(char):
    if char in ['A','B','C']:
        char = 2
    elif char in ['D','E','F']:
        char = 3
    elif char in ['G','H','I']:
        char = 4
    elif char in ['J','K','L']:
        char = 5
    elif char in ['M','N','O']:
        char = 6
    elif char in ['P','Q','R','S']:
        char = 7
    elif char in ['T','U','V']:
        char = 8
    elif char in ['W','X','Y','Z']:
        char = 9
    return char
main()
```

If you can't use `join()`

```
def check_number(user_number):
    try:
        r = ''
        for char in user_number:
            if char.isalpha():
                result = convert_to_num(char)
                r += str(result)
            else:
                r += char
        return r
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: What's the " return "".join(r)" for?

Comment: `"separator".join(list)` as the method name suggests joins strings inside a given list with `separator`. `":"join(['a','b','c'])` gives `a:b:c`. If the separator is empty string then it just joins all the characters `abc`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if char.isalpha():
    result = convert_to_num(char)
    return result
else:
    return char
```

Will return *immediately* with a single digit as the result. You want to return a string of *all* of the digits, not just the first digit, so you need to store the output digits and eventually return all of them (after the for loop is done) as a single string.

Initializing an empty list `output = []` and appending the output digits to it after each iteration of the for loop, then returning the joined list (using `"".join()`) is a good way to accomplish this.

If you aren't allowed to use `"".join()`, you can also just build up a string (`output = ""` and `output += char`) and return it directly, but this will be slower.

Comment: Where would the "output = """ and output += char go in the code, though? at the bottom of the check_numbers function? Or, the bottom of the convert_to_num function?

Comment: You would initialize the empty `output` immediately before the for loop, and append to it inside the for loop (instead of using `return`). That way, you're starting with an empty string, and appending an output character to the string on each iteration of the loop; once the loop is done your string will contain all of the output characters.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but is there any way you could type it out for me so I can *see* how the output works with the entire code. I apologize, everyone who's posted on my question has helped me a LOT, I'm just having trouble tweaking the code using the output = '', output += char (I know what they mean/do, but I'm unsure how to utilize them in this context).